# Hiding a select

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to hide all `select` elements within `.list_radio` (only), but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(".list_radio select").hide();
```

```html
<ul class="list list_radio">
  <li>
    <span class="col-md-3">
      TEXT 1
    </span>
    <div class="pull-left">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option selected=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix">
    <span class="col-md-3">
      TEXT 2
    </span>
    <div class="pull-left">
      <select class="form-control">
        <option selected=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/nfehj2L3/. Ensure there's no errors in the console, and that you've put your jQuery logic in a document.ready handler.

Comment: no errors in the console.... :/

Comment: What about the document.ready handler? If you don't understand what I mean, see this guide: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: I add but no change - ` $( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".list_radio select").hide();
  $(".list_radio").find("select").hide();
 });`

Comment: We can't help you then, as the code you've shown works - as demonstrated in the fiddle in my first comment

Comment: btw, if iwrite $(".list_radio, select").hide(); (with comma) than it's working, but it's hide ALL selectbox and not only the one inside the ".list_radio" element...

Comment: That means that your HTML does not match what you've put in the question.

Comment: thanks @RoryMcCrossan ................

Comment: wrap  your $(".list_radio select").hide();
 to a script tag and write your Script tag below the HTML code.